# how to automatically save a text on the image view?

Tags: android, performance, android-intent

i want to save a text on the image view with the different fonts on the image view in different position with the different fonts according to the user?

```
 public class FullImageActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fullimage);

    // get intent data
    Intent i = getIntent();

    // Selected image id
    int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
    ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fullimage);
    imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);
  }

}
```

Comment: you just want to put some text over an image?

Comment: as soon as the user type his text it should display on the image view with the different fonts?

Comment: then you can place a textview over imageview